# Fortran: Automatic determination of character length during initialization

Tags: fortran, character

In `Fortran` is it possible to automatically deduct the length of a character (string) when using an initializer during declaration? I want something like this (not working as it stands)

```
  character(*) :: a = 'John Doe'
  character(:) :: a = 'John Doe'
```

Example code

```
program char
  implicit none

  character(8) :: a = 'John Doe' !<-automatically?

  write(*,*) a
  write(*,*) len(a)

end program char
```

One correct way would be to use

```
  character(8) :: a = 'John Doe'
```

by simply counting the characters, which however is error-prone. Alternatively I could make the character longer than necessary and use `trim()`

```
program char
  implicit none

  character(100) :: a = 'John Doe'

  write(*,*) trim(a)
  write(*,*) len(trim(a))

end program char
```

But can the `8` be determined automatically? I am aware that this is an academic question, but I am still wondering...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @AlexanderVogt's solution using `parameter`, you can also use automatic allocation in Fortran 2003, like this:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: name
```

then initialise like this

```
name = 'John Doe'
```

and reset in the same way

```
name = 'John Doe Jr'
```

Comment: If using `allocatable` is it then mandatory to `deallocate` the variable? Wondering, since there is no explicit call of `allocate()`.

Comment: Usually, `allocatable`s are deallocated once they go out-of-scope, unless they have the `save` attribute. I also read that with Fortran 2008 `allocatables` in the main program are not necessarily deallocated, but I can't find the reference right now...

Comment: Well, when the program terminates the run-time should hand all the memory back to the operating system which is a kind of deallocation.

Comment: But before that point it is not deallocated and not finalized. That might be important for derived types. Also valgrind may notice there are still some reachable heap blocks.

Answer (score 2):

For parameters and dummy arguments you can use `character(len=*)`:

```
program char
  implicit none

  character(100) :: a = 'John Doe'
  character(len=*),parameter :: b = 'John Doe'

  write(*,*) trim(a)
  write(*,*) len_trim(a), len(a)

  write(*,*) trim(b)
  write(*,*) len_trim(b), len(b)

end program char
```

This results in:

```
./a.out 
 John Doe
           8         100
 John Doe
           8           8
```

Comment: I have accepted High Performance Mark's answer, because I think it is more likely to be helpful for future reference. But I'm actually using your method in my code, since `a` really is used as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `allocatable`:

```
character(len=LEN_TRIM('John Doe') :: a = 'John Doe'
```

If you're worried about the repetition, a parameter can be used.

Of course, an allocatable character variable has its uses, and is quite likely suitable for you, but care must be taken if you really want the variable to retain its length through various assignments:

```
a(:) = 'J. Doe'
```